# Limiting a Web Worker's resources and permissions

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe, web-worker

I am creating a web platform that will host third party applications. In order to make that secure, I need foreign scripts to run in isolated environments. In HTML5, that came down to 2 options:

- Iframes
- Web Workers

They can both prevent access to the main thread* and DOM, but they still need to be limited in terms of memory resources and internet access. Is it possible to limit the RAM a web worker/iframe can use and block access to the XHR object (and WebSockets and any other way to access the web)?

*iframes are still on the main thread I think but that's ok

Comment: Have you looked at [Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/)?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher you can make this into an answer if you want. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @KosmasPapadatos You asked about the limiting of the RAM. So Caja does answer this to you? Next limits on RAM usage, also CPU load per web worker would be managable with Caja?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace Not really. But it is the best I've found out there on this subject.

Comment: To ensure security, just use a subdomain. That's the only safe option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has done most of that heavy lifting for you with [Caja](https://developers.google.com/caja/).

They use this to create a safe 'sandbox' for adverts to run on the page while isolating them from doing too much damage.

Comment: This is no longer the case, Caja is dead, google now has a project called Closure Tools https://developers.google.com/closure/ but it's complicated and also well, google, so it'll be dead by this time next week.